# Why not use a motor inverter for charging an EV instead of using an additional onboard charger?

Tags: batteries, motor, inverter, charging

I have had this question for a long timr now but never got a satisfying answer.

Why do electric vehicles not use the built in inverter for the motor (PMSM or inductive motor) to also charge up the batteries instead of using a seperate charger? Isn't this the same thing the inverter does when the car is recuperating?

Isn't this adding an extra component, more weight and will charge slower?

Also, this would introduce many more possibilities of charging an EV fast.

The only thing that would be needed to add is some kind of switch between motor and AC socket, right?

Comment: You are thinking the VFM properties of a motor driver 0 to 100Hz+ are the same as a 50Hz to DC battery charger? Not quite !  but theoretically possible

Comment: I agree with @Tony Stewart EE75. What the motor control does during regeneration is essentially the same as it does during regeneration for braking, but there are differences. The devil is in the details. Even the "some kind of switch between motor and AC socket" is a bit more complex than you might think. Automotive design teams are quite proficient at figuring out the best balance among manufacturing cost, performance and efficiency. It some use of the motor control for charging is a good idea, they will figure it out.

Comment: I voted to close the question as a matter of opinion rather than electrical engineering design and theory.

Answer (score 2):

Some EVs do in fact use the motor inverter as part of the charging system.

However the additional complications and expense involved in making the circuit do double duty and the requirement for isolation between the battery and the incoming AC power have resulted in very few manufacturers deciding to go that route.

Some solutions even use the motor as a transformer which then introduces the complication of avoiding the motor rotating or making noise during charging.

[Valeo Charger-Inverter](https://www.valeo.com/en/charger-inverter/)

Answer (score 1):

This idea came up recently, and it turns out it’s a thing. The technique is called ‘zero-torque control’ and it uses the motor as part of the charging path.

Search for that phrase and you’ll see lots of references.

(Credit to @Neil_UK for pointing it out to me.)